# What is the difference between "mouse_event" and "SendMessage"?

Tags: python, winapi, pywin32, win32gui

I have two functions that perform clicks using pywin32.

One that uses `win32api.mouse_event`:

```
def click_1(hwnd, x, y):
    win_activate(hwnd)
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x, y))
    time.sleep(.1)

    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0)
    time.sleep(.1)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0)
```

And another that uses `win32gui.SendMessage`:

```
def click_2(hwnd, x, y):
    lparam = win32api.MAKELONG(x, y)
    win32gui.SendMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_LBUTTONDOWN, None, lparam)
    time.sleep(.1)
    win32gui.SendMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_LBUTTONUP, None, lparam)
```

I've tested both functions on several applications, and they work as expected.

However, there is one particular application where only **click_1**, the function that uses `win32api.mouse_event`, works.

We can read from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74898459/11203574) that

> A program that needs to process and respond to mouse input can decide to ignore mouse input messages. (And clients that are based on mouse message handling can easily identify fake input messages, too, and respond by, y'know, not responding altogether.)

So maybe that the application just ignore the *click messages*, but as `win32api.mouse_event` works, I would tell no.

My guess was that by using `win32api.mouse_event`, Windows would receive the message and send a new message to the window the cursor was on by using `win32gui.SendMessage`, but obviously this is not the case.

My question is: how does `win32api.mouse_event` work? Is there any way to send the same message that is sent from `win32api.mouse_event` to the window we want?

Comment: [Replaying input is not the same as reprocessing it](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20121206-00/?p=5903), in case you genuinely wonder what's different. Not that it makes a practical difference since we all know: [You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513), so why even try?

Comment: If you can't simulate mouse input with PostMessage, how can `win32gui.SendMessage` work for some windows? Is it possible that it doesn't call the `GetKeyState` function or the `GetAsyncKeyState` function? So, if the application where `win32api.mouse_event` works but not `win32gui.SendMessage` is because it does call the `GetKeyState` function or the `GetAsyncKeyState` function?

Comment: Faking input by posting input messages "works" for clients that observe mouse/keyboard messages and are otherwise indifferent to per-thread virtualized input state (exposed by `GetKeyState`). Applications that don't handle mouse or input messages are rather unimpressed by the prank call. This is common with games, for example, that interface with lower-level input APIs (such as [Raw Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/raw-input)).

Comment: "Applications that don't handle mouse or input messages are rather unimpressed by the prank call" so, how `win32api.mouse_event` can work if application does not handle mouse/input messages? And, if some application "interface with lower-level input APIs (such as Raw Input).", can't you send Raw Input message to "fake" input?

Comment: `mouse_event` (and `SendInput`) inject input events into the "hardware input queue" (see diagram [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140213-00/?p=1773)), just like mouse and keyboard drivers do. They are subjected to the entire input processing pipeline.

Comment: In the diagram [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140213-00/?p=1773), in which queue does `SendMessage` send the message? And when sending a message with `SendInput`, when is the target window "chosen"?

Comment: **Sent** messages (aka [nonqueued messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-messages-and-message-queues#nonqueued-messages)) are never queued. They go straight (more or less) to the window procedure associated with the window identified by the handle passed to the `SendMessage` call. It's approximately the bottom level of the diagram. The recipient of input events is selected just before the box that reads *"Update Input State"*.

Comment: Ok, so `SendInput` send to "hardware input queue" and `SendMessage` send directly to the window procedure. Is there any way to send any message in-between? The best would be to "fake" a `SendInput` while specifying the recipient of input.

Comment: No, there is not.

Comment: If I understand, an application can chose to handle **queued** (click) messages but not **nonqueued** (click) messages, and if it only handles **queued** messages, there is no way to specify the recipient of input because it is chosen internally? Even with `PostMessage` as it [copies the message to the message queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-messages-and-message-queues#posting-messages)?

Comment: Queued messages are initially observed by a thread's [message loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-messages-and-message-queues#message-loop). It gets to decide what to do with it: It can pass it on to the dialog manager (`IsDialogMessage`), let the system route it to the destination window (`DispatchMessage`), or ignore it altogether. Likewise, a [window procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-procedures) can decide whether to handle or ignore a message. It cannot, however, know whether a given message was initially sent or posted.

Comment: To sum up: `SendInput` send **queued** messages and the recipient of input is chosen internally. `PostMessage` and `SendMessage` send **nonqueued** messages where you must specify the recipient of input, right? And, there is no way to change the way the recipient of input is chosen? Is it always the foreground window?

Comment: `SendInput` doesn't send *any* messages. It enqueues input events into the hardware input queue, and that's all it does. Messages are posted by the system as part of input processing. `PostMessage` posts queued messages. `SendMessage` sends nonqueued messages. Keyboard input goes to the foreground window. Mouse input goes to the window under the mouse cursor. This may or may not be the foreground window.

Comment: "`PostMessage` posts **queued** messages. `SendMessage` sends **nonqueued** messages." but both *Posted* and *Sended* messages are handled differently from messages coming from the entire input processing pipeline, right? There is one handle for `SendInput`, and one handle for `PostMessage` / `SendMessage`?

Comment: No. Messages posted as a result of input processing are indiscernible from messages posted any other way. There is zero difference.

Comment: If `SendInput` works, `PostMessage` must work, but `SendMessage` may not (because it queues **nonqueued** messages)? So, as you can specify the recipient of input when **posting** message, you can "fake" a `SendInput` message using `PostMessage`?

Comment: *"If `SendInput` works, `PostMessage` must work"* - No. Input messages posted to message queues are merely one side effect of input processing. There are several other observable side effects of input processing. Interactive applications can choose to handle and ignore any combination of those side effects.

Comment: Can you reopen this question to allow me to summarize our discussion in a reply, as there is (a lot of) information not included in the "duplicated" post?

Comment: What information would you like to see in the duplicate target that's not there already?